# Querying many-to-many association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I'm learning rails and I'm stuck with a query. My models have a many-to-many relationship. It's hard to explain the models that I'm using as they are too specific to my domain of work, so I'll use the example from [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association) with slight modification.

Here's the model:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :appointment_time

  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

I want a list of patients with their Appointment.appointment_time.
I can list all the patients associated with a physician using `physician.patients`. How can I include the appointment time as well? I can think of querying Appointments once I have the list of patients, but I was wondering if there is a "rails" way of doing this (something like `physician.patients_with_appointments`). If not, what's the efficient way to do this?

Comment: why don't you want use 'physician.patients.include(:appointments)' ?

Comment: be aware that you may not get an answer that applies to your specific code, because you have chosen to use fake code examples instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
physician.appointments.includes(:patients).each do |appointment|
  puts appointment.appointment_time
  puts appointment.patient.name
end
```

**This is not tested

As far as I know the rails way you are looking for doesn't really exist. To make sure you are not loading each one on every loop you can use an includes. I am not sure if I am putting the includes in the right place because I do not have access to rails console at the moment.

If there are a lot of records you may want to batch find using find_each but for your example this should work.

Comment: this makes more sense, because then you can also do things like order on the appointment time.

Answer (score 0):

As phil.ts said:

```
patients = physician.patients.include(:appointments)
```

will do the trick.

now when you do:

```
patients.appointment
```

the database won't need an extra query since rails knows to include them in the first query.

Comment: `patients.appointment` will error because `patients` is an ActiveRecord::Relation. You're also including `appointments` not `appointment`,  so for each patient you'll have an array of appointments, not just one.